# Trying to compile an open-source program for Mac, failing to get Cocoa file requester and Menus working

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to compile XRoar for Mac OS High Sierra (https://www.6809.org.uk/xroar/). I've made a binary which runs and takes command-line arguments, but I have no Menus and no load/save file interactions once the program is running

A compiled binary for XRoar 0.32 is available, but it seems to be glitchy (sound, graphics & speed) on Mac OS High Sierra. I'm trying to compile version 0.35 and the limited version I've created seems fine in terms of glitches. I've tried invoking both versions of XRoar directly from the command line and you can see them pulling in slightly different modules:

Pre-compiled XRoar 0.32:
Module init: Mac OS X SDL UI
Module init: Cocoa file requester
Module init: SDL OpenGL video
Module init: Mac OS X audio

"My" compiled XRoar 0.35:
Module init: SDL2 UI
Module init: No file requester
Module init: SDL2 video
Module init: Mac OS X audio

XRoar is compiled with these three steps:

```
 $ ./configure
 $ make
 $ sudo make install
```

I have no idea how to "tell" it to use the Mac OS X SDL UI, Cocoa file requester etc. I guess some arguments after configure but I don't know what the syntax would be.

I also wondered whether this would help:
https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php
I've copied the SDL2.framework to `/Library/Frameworks` but it doesn't seem to have helped.

I wonder what the person who compiled XRoar 0.32 did to give it nice menus, file access etc.

I realise I've early on in the learning curve wrt compiling for Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

So I replied to this elsewhere, but the gist is:  I don't have a modern enough Mac so haven't been able to keep the mac-specific code up to date with changes to other parts.  Also, I migrated other platforms to SDL2 after that, but SDL1.2 builds still work.  Best bet is to use SDL1.2 (run configure with "--without-sdl2" if you have both installed), try building, then start hacking...

Comment: ... and since then I've been gifted the use of my other half's old mac which I'm now able to homebrew up.  The dev branch now contains the requisite fixes to get it building with SDL1.2.